# NIDAQmx continuous adquisition with python

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I am using a [nidaqmx](https://nidaqmx-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python3 pacakge to program the NI PCI-6133 acquisition board, and I **can't use the board in continuous acquisition mode**. It doesn't give an error, but I can't see the buffer values. I can read some values using this package. I am based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366033/continuous-acquistion-with-nidaqmx).
My Code:

```
import nidaqmx
from nidaqmx import stream_readers
import numpy as np
import time 

data2=np.zeros((1, 10000), dtype=np.float32)
system=nidaqmx.system.System.local()
print("Driver version nidaqmx:",system.driver_version)
#19.6

for device in system.devices:
    print("Device:", device)

syst=nidaqmx.system.system.System()

with nidaqmx.Task() as task:

    task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0",min_val=-10.0,max_val=10.0)
    task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(rate=10000,
                                      active_edge=nidaqmx.constants.Edge.RISING,
                                      sample_mode=nidaqmx.constants.AcquisitionType.CONTINUOUS,
                                      samps_per_chan=10000)
    reader =stream_readers.AnalogMultiChannelReader(task.in_stream)

    def reading_task_callback(task_idx, event_type, num_samples, callback_data=None):
        """After data has been read into the NI buffer this callback is called to read in the                                        data from the buffer.

        This callback is for working with the task callback register_every_n_samples_acquired_into_buffer_event.

        Args:
            task_idx (int): Task handle index value
            event_type (nidaqmx.constants.EveryNSamplesEventType): ACQUIRED_INTO_BUFFER
            num_samples (int): Number of samples that was read into the buffer.
            callback_data (object)[None]: No idea. Documentation says: The callback_data parameter contains the value
                you passed in the callback_data parameter of this function.
        """
        buffer = np.zeros((1, num_samples), dtype=np.float32)
        reader.read_many_sample(buffer, num_samples, timeout=nidaqmx.constants.WAIT_INFINITELY)

        # Convert the data from channel as a row order to channel as a column
        data = buffer.T.astype(np.float32)

        # Do something with the data
        print("Hello")
        print(data)

        return 0 # callback must return an integer, otherwise callback throws a wall of errors

    task.register_every_n_samples_acquired_into_buffer_event(10000, reading_task_callback)
```

Output:

```
Driver version nidaqmx: DriverVersion(major_version=19, minor_version=6, update_version=0)
Device: Device(name=Dev1)
```

Additionaly I use NI I/O trace for monitor the communication with the board:

```
1.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQMajorVersion (19 (0x13))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:39,6679      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

2.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQMinorVersion (6 (0x6))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:39,7099      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

3.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQUpdateVersion (0 (0x0))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:39,7509      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

4.  DAQmxGetSysDevNames (0x053C4A58, 0 (0x0))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:39,8709      Call Duration 00:00:00.0439
Status: 5 (0x5)

5.  DAQmxGetSysDevNames ("Dev1", 5 (0x5))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:39,9579      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

6.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQMajorVersion (19 (0x13))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,0279      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

7.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQMinorVersion (6 (0x6))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,0689      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

8.  DAQmxGetSysNIDAQUpdateVersion (0 (0x0))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,1099      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

9.  DAQmxCreateTask ("", 0x6A1621A0)
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,1509      Call Duration 00:00:00.0059
Status: 0 (0x0)

10.  DAQmxGetTaskName (0x6A1621A0, "", 0 (0x0))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,1979      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 16 (0x10)

11.  DAQmxGetTaskName (0x6A1621A0, "_unnamedTask<0>", 16 (0x10))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,2389      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

12.  DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan (0x6A1621A0, "Dev1/ai0", "", "DAQmx_Val_Cfg_Default", -10.000000 (-1.000000E+01), 10.000000 (1.000000E+01), DAQmx_Val_Volts, "")
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,2799      Call Duration 00:00:00.0130
Status: 0 (0x0)

13.  DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming (0x6A1621A0, "", 10000.000000 (1.000000E+04), DAQmx_Val_Rising, DAQmx_Val_ContSamps, 10000 (0x0000000000002710))
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,3359      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)

14.  DAQmxRegisterEveryNSamplesEvent (0x6A1621A0, "DAQmx_Val_Acquired_Into_Buffer", 10000 (0x2710), 0 (0x0), 0x00FD0FDC,    NULL   )
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,3769      Call Duration 00:00:00.0039
Status: 0 (0x0)

15.  DAQmxClearTask (0x6A1621A0)
Process ID: 0x00001DBC         Thread ID: 0x00000C18
Start Time: 07:49:40,4219      Call Duration 00:00:00.0000
Status: 0 (0x0)
```

Some help, ideally a code or modification from my code that can use the board in continues mode and extract the values from the buffer.